# In RCA0, Prove that for all n, fⁿ(i) exists

Tags: first-order-logic, peano-axioms, second-order-logic, reverse-math

I wanted to prove in RCA0 that:

If f:A→A be a function and i∈A, then for all n, fⁿ(i) exists.

To reach that, I proved another theorem. I wrote my proof but I'm not sure it's rigorous. If you read it, please tell me it is, or it is not.

Theorem:

Suppose f:A→A be a function and i∈A. Then for all n, there is a unique sequence a s.t
lh(a)=n+1 and ∀k<n ( a(k+1)=f(a(k)) )

Proof:

Let P be this formula:
P(n): ∃x [ x∈seq ∧ lh(x)=n+1 ∧ x(0)=i ∧
∀k<n (  x(k+1)=f(x(k)) ) ]
We use sigma0-1 induction to prove ∀n P(n).
P(0) is obviously true. Suppose that P(n) holds. So there is a sequence x satisfies the conditions. Define sequence y like this:
lh(y)=n+2 and ∀k<n+1 ( y(k)=x(k) ) and
y(n+1)=f(y(n))
So y satisfies the conditions and P(n+1) holds.
So, by induction, ∀n P(n).

For uniqness, suppose x and y are two different sequence satisfy the conditions for n. let m<n+1 be a number s.t  ¬( x(m)=y(m) ). Without loss of generality, let m be the least element by this property. So x(m-1)=y(m-1). Then f(x(m-1))=f(y(m-1)) that means x(m)=y(m). Contradiction.

For arbitrary n, define fⁿ(i)=a(n). So we've proved that for all n, fⁿ(i) exists.